# Manter aplicação (Windows Form) aberta na bandeja de ícones com C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

Como fazer que ao fechar a aplicação (seja por botão de fechar, <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>, ou qualquer outro método que não o gerenciador de processos), a aplicação continue rodando na bandeja de ícones do Windows:

[image: Bandeja de ícones]

E é muito complicado fazer um menu para quando clicar com o botão de contexto (geralmente botão direito do *mouse*) sobre o ícone da aplicação na bandeja?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fazer não é, resolver tudo o que isto implica pode ser um pouco mais. Para te passar tudo o que é necessário seria muito longo. Você pode ir fazendo perguntas específicas. Para te dar uma base para começar eu achei uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250051/221800) que pode fazer um teste.

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.Run(new MyCustomApplicationContext());
    }
}


public class MyCustomApplicationContext : ApplicationContext {
    private NotifyIcon trayIcon;

    public MyCustomApplicationContext() {
        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon() {
            Icon = Resources.AppIcon,
            ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem[] {
                new MenuItem("Exit", Exit)
            }),
            Visible = true
        };
    }

    void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Hide tray icon, otherwise it will remain shown until user mouses over it
        trayIcon.Visible = false;
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/TrayIcon.cs).

Um [tutorial mais completo](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/).

Answer (score 5):

Para mandar a aplicação para a bandeja do sistema , você pode adicionar um `NotifyIcon` no *designer* do seu `form` e deixá-lo visível sempre que fores minizar ou (nesse caso) fechar a aplicação.

Para adicionar um menu de contexto no seu `NotifyIcon` você pode adicionar um `ContextMenuStrip` (ainda no *designer* do *form*) e vincular o menu ao `NotifyIcon` usando a propriedade `ContextMenuStrip`.

Para mostrar o `NotifyIcon` sempre que a aplicação for **fechada**, você pode implementar o evento `FormClosing` no seu *form* principal, seria algo como:

```
public form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; // Cancelar o fechamento do form
    Hide(); // Ocultar o form
    // use this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; para minimizar
    notifyIcon.Visible = true; // Mostrar o notify icon
}
```

---

Um ponto importante é que você não pode esquecer de tirar a visibilidade do seu `NotifyIcon` antes de fechar a aplicação, pois, caso contrário, o ícone permanecerá na bandeja do sistema até que o usuário passe o *mouse* por cima do ícone. (Não sei o porquê desse comportamento, mas já sofri muito com ele).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Acrescentar no form o "notifyIcon";
2) Acrescentar código no evento "notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick";
3) Código:
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Aplicação minimizada";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
        }

        else if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Aplicação maximizada";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
        }

4) Código no botão que minimiza:
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide(); // Ocultar o form
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```